# Ending lines of text inside a commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, text, commutative-diagrams

Consider the following diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{This is a sentence} \arrow[r, "\phi"] & x
\end{tikzcd}
```

I wish for the "This is" to be *above* "a sentence". I've tried using `\\` to signal a new line, yet that merely causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `tabular`. If it's a one-off, then

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}This is \\ a sentence\end{tabular} \arrow[r, "\phi"] & x
\end{tikzcd}
```

is what you need. For several of these you may want a personal command, for instance

```
\newcommand{\splitentry}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
```

and your code would become

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  \splitentry{This is \\ a sentence} \arrow[r, "\phi"] & x
\end{tikzcd}
```

I added an optional argument for the vertical alignment (default `c`). Try with

```
\splitentry[t]{This is \\ a sentence}
\splitentry[b]{This is \\ a sentence}
```

to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{\makecell{This is\\a sentence}} \arrow[r, "\phi"] & x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can create a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\mycell}[1]{\text{\makecell{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  \mycell{This is\\ a sentence} \arrow[r, "\phi"] & x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is:

[image]